# Javascript function creation

Tags: javascript, function

I have a code that when clicked upon displays information snippets in a bubble popup effect, and that works perfectly, but i wanted to change the on click code below to a function that i would be able to call upon from another javascript? could anyone help a newbie to javascript??
Highly appreciate it .

```
dot[0].onclick = function (e) {

    locX = e.pageX - 250;
    locY = e.pageY - 300;


    if (!isPopup) {

        isPopup = true;
        popup = r.rect(locX, locY, 50, 50, 5)
           .attr({ fill: "#66000000" });
        text = r.text(locX + 20, locY + 20, lbl.node.textContent).attr(txt)
            .attr({ fill: "#eee" });

    }
    else {
        popup.hide();
        text.hide();
        popup = r.rect(locX, locY, 50, 50, 5)
           .attr({ fill: "#66000000" });
        text = r.text(locX + 20, locY + 20, lbl.node.textContent).attr(txt)
            .attr({ fill: "#eee" });


    }
    e.stopPropagation();

};
```

Comment: New Bees either learn how to program (in that case you have to ask something more particular rather than "please do this work for me") or hire real developers. Choose whichever is more suitable for you.

Comment: Sally - you could put the code into a straight function (`function popupBubble(event) { locX = e.pageX - 250; ... }`), but as it stands, the code uses the event object to set things like position, so if you were to put the code into a separate function, you would have to ensure you called it using an event trigger and pass the event along.

Comment: Thanks for the insightful comment @Raad that was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function yourOnclickFunction(e) {
    // ...
}
dot[0].onclick = yourOnclickFunction;
```